# Не получается настроить переброс меток через прокладку

Tags: php, html, html5, get, редирект

Задача следующая: есть лендинг, на него трафик приходит с метками, эти метки нужно передать дальше.

**Пример**

Ссылка, которая используется для направления траффика на сайт:

```
https://yandex-dzen.site/?utm_source=1&utm_medium=1&utm_campaign=1&utm_content=1&utm_term=1&MDappstore=1&MDdev=1&MDrefferer=1&MDpage=1&MDtimestamp=1&MDdomain=1&MDuser=1&GAID=1&MDexchange=1&MDcreative=1&MDcampaign=1
```

Для перенаправления дальше использую .php файл с кодом, на него направляем обычным href="googleplay2.php"

```
<?php
$click_id=$_GET['utm_source'] ?? ''; 
$source_id=$_GET['utm_medium'] ?? '';  
$MDapp_id=$_GET['utm_campaign'] ?? '';
$MDapp_name=$_GET['utm_content'] ?? '';
$MDsite_id=$_GET['utm_term'] ?? '';
$MDappstore_url=$_GET['MDappstore'] ?? '';
$MDdev_model=$_GET['MDdev'] ?? '';
$MDrefferer=$_GET['MDrefferer'] ?? '';
$MDpage_url=$_GET['MDpage'] ?? '';
$MDtimestamp=$_GET['MDtimestamp'] ?? '';
$MDdomain=$_GET['MDdomain'] ?? '';
$MDuser_id=$_GET['MDuser'] ?? '';
$MD_GAID=$_GET['GAID'] ?? '';
$MDexchange=$_GET['MDexchange'] ?? '';
$MDcreative_id=$_GET['MDcreative'] ?? '';
$MDcampaign_id=$_GET['MDcampaign'] ?? ''; 
$link='https://redirect.appmetrica.yandex.com/serve/674048837559559848?c=MyDSP&'.$click_id.'&'.$source_id.'&'.$MDapp_id.'&'.$MDapp_name.'&'.$MDsite_id.'&'.$MDappstore_url.'&'.$MDdev_model.'&'.$MDrefferer.'&'.$MDpage_url.'&'.$MDtimestamp.'&'.$MDdomain.'&'.$MDuser_id.'&'.$MD_GAID.'&'.$MDexchange.'&'.$MDcreative_id.'&'.$MDcampaign_id;
?>  

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=<?=$link?>">
```

В итоге, редирект получается таким:

```
https://redirect.appmetrica.yandex.ru/serve/674048837559559848?c=MyDSP&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&yandex_uid_com=5140035721521533240;70d39c33d6d0cf8ed72e95b8eda22592e71d2e00;1522754203&header_referer=https://yandex-dzen.site/googleplay2.php
```

На сервере файл index в формате php. Версия php - 7

С чем связана проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно проверить что находиться в массиве `$_GET`.

Можно использовать такой подход для формирование ссылки:

```
$arguments = array_map(function($k,$v){
    return $k.'='.$v;
}, array_keys($_GET), $_GET);
$link='https://redirect.appmetrica.yandex.com/serve/674048837559559848?c=MyDSP&'.implode('&',$arguments);

var_dump($link);
```

`